# Iptables spoofing from 2 subnets

Tags: iptables

I have packets from 2 subnets going into my firewall eth1:

10.111.12.0/24 and 10.10.100.0/24

I set iptables rules like that:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 ! -s 10.111.12.0/24 -j DROP
 iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 ! -s 10.10.100.0/24 -j DROP
```

But - the first rule doesnt allow to check the second one  because 10.10.100.0/24 is NOT 10.111.12.0/24 and it is matching first rule. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to mark allowed packets and later drop all packets that are not marked:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s 10.111.12.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s 10.10.100.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -m mark ! --mark 1 -j DROP
```

You should consider that there might be other packets that you need/want to get through.

Answer (score 5):

A chain would be a useful method here.  A chain acts somewhat like a subroutine or function.  The RETURN just means the control for that packet will be return to the previous chain and rules will continue to be evaluated.

```
# create a new chain
iptables -t filter -N in_validnet

# all incoming packets on eth1 are evaluated by the chain
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i eth1 -j in_validnet

# packets from these networks are returned for further evaluation
iptables -A in_validnet -s 10.111.12.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -A in_validnet -s 10.10.100.0/24 -j RETURN

# everything else gets dropped
iptables -A in_validnet -j DROP
```